# How do I toggle Magit enumerating untracked files?

Tags: magit

`git status` in my configuration is extremely slow at enumerating untracked files, for reasons not relevant here. I'd like to have Magit use the `-uno` argument in most cases, in order to avoid a long delay every time I refresh the buffer, but also have the option of doing a full status (including untracked files) at will.

I'm not seeing a way to make this happen without modifying or advising Magit's code and mode map; there doesn't seem either to be an "ignore untracked files" option, or an option to add arbitrary command arguments to the `git status` invocation. Have I missed something, or do I have some hacking to do?

Comment: We both should delete that parts that are misunderstandings and clarifications. It will then be easier to answer the actual question.

Comment: @tarsius Agreed and done.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default value of the Git variable `status.showUntrackedFiles` is `normal`. In that case both `git status` and `magit-status` only lists directories containing untracked files (and untracked files at the top-level).

If you set it to `all`, then `git status` lists all individual untracked files, but it *appears* as if `magit-status` isn't affected. However it is now possible to expand such a directory section.  <kbd>TAB</kbd> on `foo/` in

```
Untracked files (1)
foo/
```

shows

```
Untracked files (1)
foo/
foo/a
foo/b
```

The `(1)` is a bit unfortunate.

If the value is `all` and until `foo/` is expanded, Magit actually pretends the value is `normal`. I have updated the documentation accordingly.

The reason Magit does it this way, is that `all` can be very costly and we cannot assume that users realize that setting this variable also affects Magit.

Comment: according to the `git status` man page, `-uno` is short for `--untracked-files=no`

Comment: Thank you very much for the pointer to the correct repository! That's what I get for trusting Google to do the right thing when I search for "magit changelog"...

Comment: How to change the variable: `git config status.showUntrackedFiles all`

Answer (score 2):

customize the `magit-section-initial-visibility-alist` set key to `untracked` and value to `hide`

`(setq magit-section-initial-visibility-alist (quote ((untracked . hide))))`

or you can do this through the emacs customize interface.

this will make untracked file hidden initially.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just go to the un-tracked files heading and press `TAB`. It will fold it like an orgmode buffer heading.

Comment: I guess he can only do that when the files have been enumerated, ie too late... unless magit can "remember" that for next time?

Comment: It does remember after setting it the first time if you don't kill the process even after changes and running magit-status a second time. If you kill the buffer though you will have to do it again. Not perfect fix but definitely simple.

Comment: Not the solution I'm looking for, but it does address the question I actually asked in the title. I've updated that to better reflect my intent. Thanks for drawing attention to the mismatch!