# Disabling Magit's untracked files status

Tags: magit

I'm trying out Magit for a monstrously large monorepo at work (think millions of lines of code) and there are many untracked build artifacts. From my shell I always use `git status -uno` to avoid having git try to unenumerate all of the artifacts that should be ignored but aren't.

I wish I could just add things to the `.gitignore` files, but sadly this is just not feasible (layer 8 problem in the networking stack...).

*Can I configure magit to not interact with untracked files at all when refreshing?*

I found [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27271/how-do-i-toggle-magit-enumerating-untracked-files), but I don't want to just hide the untracked section, but avoid the mega latency from git attempting to enumerate the thousands of untracked files (that I don't care about).

Comment: Can't you just modify ```.gitignore``` in your own local branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If telling git to ignore those untracked files to `.gitignore` would solve your problem, then do that. You can't modify the `.gitignore` files, ok, so use [another method](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

- `.git/info/exclude` (same effect as `.gitignore` at the root, except that it only applies in this working tree).
- `~/.config/git/ignore` (same effect as `.gitignore` at the root, except that it applies to all your working trees).

Comment: This effectively solves my problem (borrowing someone else's gitignore file from within the company). Thanks!